# Pag Seguro Checkout Transparente - Unauthorized

Tags: php, javascript, libcurl

Estou com problema para finalizar o checkout transparente do pag seguro, segue o código do que estou vazendo

```
$url = "https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions";
$dados = 'email=paulocentr@gmail.com&token=6128AD81C3E1487CA564B23D28D91577&paymentMode=default&paymentMethod=boleto&currency=BRL&notificationURL=http://pjdesign.zapto.org/newalternativa/notify&reference=ABCD123&senderName=Paulo José&senderCPF=11111111111&senderAreaCode=11&senderPhone=11&senderEmail=paulocentr@hotmail.com&senderHash=36f5be1b09a8f3af3a8489cf9ae1d3539884e2012a266f1c303176b6baf381ff&shippingAddressStreet=Rua Getúlio Vargas&shippingAddressNumber=11&shippingAddressComplement=&shippingAddressDistrict=Alto da Boa Vista&shippingAddressPostalCode=75523170&shippingAddressCity=Itumbiara&shippingAddressState=GO&shippingAddressCountry=BRA&shippingType=3&shippingCost=160.00&itemId1=1748&itemDescription1=Shape Adesivado E Pintura Verniz Automotivo&itemAmount1=63.25&itemQuantity1=1';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($xml == 'Unauthorized'){
        echo 'O servidor encontra se temporariamente indisponível';
        printvetor($xml);
        exit;
}
```

Definitivamente, segui todas as instruções da documentação e sempre entra no Unauthorized, alguem que ja tenha feito essa integração pode me ajudar?

Comment: "Unauthorized" significa que ou o e-mail ou o token está errado. Outra coisa que pode ser é que o ambiente está trocado: sandbox ou produção. Lembre-se de que cada ambiente tem um token diferente.

Comment: Verifique se o email é o que você usou no cadastro de sua conta no pagseguro e seu token é realmente o token usado na sandbox. Você pode verificar aqui -> https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/ logandando com sua conta, Perfis de integração, Vendedor.

Comment: No meu caso, estava funcionando normal no ambiente de produção e começou a dar "Unauthorized" do nada. Aí tive que logar e gerar um novo token, daí funcionou. Imagino que tenha expirado o token antigo.